# SearchView MenutItemCompat doesn't collapse

Tags: android

I am trying to collapse my searchview after searching using the support library but i can't get my search view to collaspe

```
 final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), PanelActivity.class);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                    searchManager.getSearchableInfo(cn));
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

                    searchView.clearFocus();
                    searchView.setIconified(true);
                    MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchItem);
                    // hideKeyboard();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what ever the reason I've ran into this problem too.

Invoking setIconified twice fixed it. Try:

```
searchView.setIconified(true);
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

Comment: This works I had to do something like this for another support library function. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this. for **ActionBarCompat**(Auto close after event cick)

Just below //ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), PanelActivity.class);

```
MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(searchItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
            | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

Good Luck

Comment: I have tried this menu option before it causes weird things to happen to my action bar